# strange behaviour of Set of Matrices in Julia

Tags: matrix, set, julia

having a set of matrices, when looping through them and modifying them, I'm unable to delete them from the set:

```
julia> grids = Set([[1 2;3 4],[3 4;5 6]])
Set{Matrix{Int64}} with 2 elements:
  [1 2; 3 4]
  [3 4; 5 6]

julia> for g in grids
           g[g .== 3] .= 0
           println(g)
           println(grids)
           delete!(grids,g)
       end
[1 2; 0 4]
Set([[1 2; 0 4], [3 4; 5 6]])
[0 4; 5 6]
Set([[1 2; 0 4], [0 4; 5 6]])

julia> println(grids)
Set([[1 2; 0 4], [0 4; 5 6]])
```

however manual delete works:

```
julia> grids = Set([[1 2;3 4],[3 4;5 6]])
Set{Matrix{Int64}} with 2 elements:
  [1 2; 3 4]
  [3 4; 5 6]

julia> delete!(grids, [1 2;3 4])
Set{Matrix{Int64}} with 1 element:
  [3 4; 5 6]
```

What am I missing please? I assumed the `g` in the loop behaves like a pointer to certain matrix, but it doesn't. Clearly, I am missing some Julia concept here...

Comment: What are you doing there, anyway? This might be an XY-problem.

Comment: @phipsgabler I tried to simplify the question here, maybe it doesn't make much sense with no context. It was part of the solution of https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/4 (I simply needed a structure of matrices, to be continuously updated and checked for some condition. If true, then I needed to delete the matrix from that structure). It was easy to do it with many other ways, but this behaviour surprised me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely want to use `IdDict` not `Set` in this case:

```
julia> grids = IdDict([[1 2;3 4],[3 4;5 6]] .=> nothing)
IdDict{Matrix{Int64}, Nothing} with 2 entries:
  [1 2; 3 4] => nothing
  [3 4; 5 6] => nothing

julia> for g in keys(grids)
                  g[g .== 3] .= 0
                  println(g)
                  println(grids)
                  delete!(grids,g)
              end
[1 2; 0 4]
IdDict([1 2; 0 4] => nothing, [3 4; 5 6] => nothing)
[0 4; 5 6]
IdDict([0 4; 5 6] => nothing)

julia> grids
IdDict{Matrix{Int64}, Nothing}()
```

The difference is that `IdDict` makes lookup on matrix identity, while `Set` makes lookup on matrix contents.

Note though that `IdDict` can store two matrices having identical contents as separate entries if they are not stored in the same memory location (as tested with `===`):

```
julia> IdDict([1;;] => nothing, [1;;] => nothing)
IdDict{Matrix{Int64}, Nothing} with 2 entries:
  [1;;] => nothing
  [1;;] => nothing
```

so you need to choose what kind of behavior you want.

Alternatively you should delete the element from a `Set` before mutating it:

```
julia> grids = Set([[1 2;3 4],[3 4;5 6]])
Set{Matrix{Int64}} with 2 elements:
  [1 2; 3 4]
  [3 4; 5 6]

julia> for g in grids
                  println(grids)
                  delete!(grids,g)
                  g[g .== 3] .= 0
                  println(g)
              end
Set([[1 2; 3 4], [3 4; 5 6]])
[1 2; 0 4]
Set([[3 4; 5 6]])
[0 4; 5 6]

julia> grids
Set{Matrix{Int64}}()
```

To expand on the problem more see:

```
julia> a = [1]
1-element Vector{Int64}:
 1

julia> x = Set([a])
Set{Vector{Int64}} with 1 element:
  [1]

julia> a in x
true

julia> a[1] = 2
2

julia> x
Set{Vector{Int64}} with 1 element:
  [2]

julia> a in x
false
```

So although `x` shows that it stores `a` the lookup of `a` fails, because `Set` performs the lookup based on `hash` value of `a` computed at the time `a` was stored in `x` and if you change the contents of `a` its `hash` changes.

In short:

1. You can store mutable values in `Set`, but then do not mutate them for lookup;
2. Alternatively you can use `IdDict` that does lookup using object identity not object value.

Comment: Which is the reason Python disallows this kind of usage (by not having hash functions for lists in the first place).

Comment: thanks! I understand there are better structures for this case, but still - is there any way how to force the recalculation of hashes of the Set (except the obvious, i.e. deleting the elements and adding mutated ones...)?

Comment: AFAICT `Base.rehash!(grids.dict))` should work, but it is not part of public API and it would be slow (you need to recalculate hashes for all entries in `Set`). In short - I would not recommend it.